# Taking the content from a trimmed cell and displaying in a different format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an extract from an internal system that shows the date and timestamp of when a merchant was activated in our system (column K) - which comes from a system export.
I'm trying to get this changed so it is displayed in YYY-MM format - like in Column J (I've tried just changing the type, but that doesn't work)

In Column O, I've taken the value in Column K and, if it's not blank, trimmed the characters off the end, so it's just in date format.
Then, in column P, taken the value of the result in Column O, and changed the type to Custom (YYY-MM) - but the date displayed is wrong.

Cell contents:

K: 16.02.23 16:54:02016000

O: =IF(K5651="","",LEFT(K5651,(LEN(K5651)-15)))

P: =IF(O5651="","",PRODUCT(O5651))

What am I doing wrong, or, is ther a simpler way to do this without loads of columns?

Thanks!

[image: Excel]

Comment: May be something like this should work: `=TEXT(TEXTBEFORE(K5651," ")+0,"mmm-yy")` but why do you use `PRODUCT()` function? or `TEXTBEFORE(K5651," ")+0` format cell.

Comment: =DATE(MID(K5651,7,2),MID(K5651,4,2),LEFT(K5651,2)) and then format as "mmm-yy" or wrap it in TEXT:  =TEXT(DATE(MID(K5651,7,2),MID(K5651,4,2),LEFT(K5651,2)),"mmm-yy")

Comment: Thank you, user11222393
That fixed it :)

Comment: This is a case where your work would be a lot simpler if the data you were working on was the right format.  If Col K was an actual date, then you could just use TEXT on it.  Otherwise you're in this complicated text manipulation thing like user11222393 suggests.  How is this data populated?  Can you just export it as a date?